# find record within a group further subsetted by certain values and mutate a flag

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have an example df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e"),
  col1 = c(-36,10,-5,1, 0, 5,10, 5, 20, 2, -1, 1, 2, -10, -5, -1, 10 )

)

   group col1
1      a  -36
2      a   10
3      a   -5
4      a    1
5      b    0
6      b    5
7      c   10
8      c    5
9      c   20
10     c    2
11     d   -1
12     d    1
13     d    2
14     e  -10
15     e   -5
16     e   -1
17     e   10
```

and I want to mutate a flag such that if grouped by 'group, if there is a value of 1 in col1, set that to "Y" and all other records in that group to blank. If there is a value of less than or equal to one, set the record with the highest col1 to "Y" and all other records in that group to blank (but col1 cannot be greater than 1 - these records must have blank flag).  Otherwise, set every record to blank. Every record above value of 1 should have blank flag.

This is what I've tried:

```
df3 <- df %>% mutate(flag = case_when(
  any(col1 == 1) ~ ifelse(col1 == 1, "Y", ""),
  any(col1 < 1) & !any(col1 == 1) ~ ifelse(col1 < 1 & col1 == max(col1), "Y", ""),
  TRUE ~ ""))
```

This is the expected outcome:

```
   group col1 flag
1      a  -36     
2      a   10     
3      a   -5     
4      a    1    Y
5      b    0    Y
6      b    5     
7      c   10     
8      c    5     
9      c   20     
10     c    2     
11     d   -1     
12     d    1    Y
13     d    2     
14     e  -10     
15     e   -5     
16     e   -1    Y
17     e   10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `if/else` condition after grouping by 'group'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(flag = c("", "Y")[1+ (if(1 %in% col1) col1 == 1 else 
    if(any(col1 < 1))  col1 == max(col1[col1 <= 1]) else FALSE)]) %>% 
 # compact version with a warning
 #  mutate(flag = c("", "Y")[1+(col1 == max(col1[col1 <=1], na.rm = TRUE))]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 × 3
   group  col1 flag 
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1 a       -36 ""   
 2 a        10 ""   
 3 a        -5 ""   
 4 a         1 "Y"  
 5 b         0 "Y"  
 6 b         5 ""   
 7 c        10 ""   
 8 c         5 ""   
 9 c        20 ""   
10 c         2 ""   
11 d        -1 ""   
12 d         1 "Y"  
13 d         2 ""   
14 e       -10 ""   
15 e        -5 ""   
16 e        -1 "Y"  
17 e        10 ""
```

Comment: just wanted to ask for my own knowledge, with the compact version, why does it have the warning and in the non-compact version, how is it able to bypass the warning?

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `case_when`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(group) |>
  mutate(flag = case_when(
           col1 > 1 ~ "",
           col1 == 1 ~ "Y",
           col1 == max(col1[col1 <= 1]) ~ "Y",
           TRUE ~ ""
         ))
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [5]
#>    group  col1 flag 
#>    <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 a       -36 ""   
#>  2 a        10 ""   
#>  3 a        -5 ""   
#>  4 a         1 "Y"  
#>  5 b         0 "Y"  
#>  6 b         5 ""   
#>  7 c        10 ""   
#>  8 c         5 ""   
#>  9 c        20 ""   
#> 10 c         2 ""   
#> 11 d        -1 ""   
#> 12 d         1 "Y"  
#> 13 d         2 ""   
#> 14 e       -10 ""   
#> 15 e        -5 ""   
#> 16 e        -1 "Y"  
#> 17 e        10 ""
```

Comment: If there are any max(col1[col1 <= 1]) that returns the error: 'no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf', how can I resolve it or change the code to prevent this warning?

Comment: you could pipe `suppressWarnings()` at the end.